# How to make an array of triangles collide with eachother?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have an empty array which gets new elements added to it with every update. These are triangles that fall from the top of the screen to the bottom. How would i go about making these triangles interact with eachother. I want them to collide with eachother but every tutorial i've found has been no help.

```js
let PARTICLES = [];
//Creates canvas of 400x650 pixels
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 650);
}

//Creates new particles and adds them to the Particles[] array
function draw() {
  background("turquoise");
  let newP = new Particle();
  PARTICLES.push(newP);
  //Continously +1 to the PARTICLES array which duplicated the original triangle.
  for (let i = 0; i < PARTICLES.length; i++) {
    PARTICLES[i].update();
    PARTICLES[i].show();
    if(PARTICLES[i].delete()) {
      PARTICLES.splice(i,1);           //keeps the array 78 elements long
    }
  }
}

//Gives the position of the original particle that all the others are copied from
class Particle {
  constructor() {
    this.x1 = 195;
    this.y1 = 30;
    this.x2 = 200;
    this.y2 = 20;
    this.x3 = 205;
    this.y3 = 30;
    this.vx = random(-0.8, 0.8);
    this.vy = 8;
  }
  
  //if the y position of a particle gets >650, it is deleted from the array
  delete() {
    return this.y1 > 650;
  }
  
  //updates every vertex with the speed given to it
  update() {
    this.x1 += this.vx;
    this.y1 += this.vy;
    this.x2 += this.vx;
    this.y2 += this.vy;
    this.x3 += this.vx;
    this.y3 += this.vy;  
  }
  
  //Triangle properties
  show() {
    stroke(255);
    fill(255, 10);
    triangle(this.x1, this.y1, this.x2, this.y2, this.x3, this.y3);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="p5.collide2D.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify your problem: what behaviour do you expect, what error are you getting, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use p5 myself, but the basics are the same for any library: test each object for overlap with another object and when that occurs take some action: e.g. alter the position of one, or both, of the objects so they are no longer colliding.

A look at the main `p5.js` library shows that it has a plugin libary called `p5.collide2d` that you can use. This library has the function [collidePolyPoly()](https://github.com/bmoren/p5.collide2D#collidepolypoly) to check whether 2 polygons intersect.

Here's an official demo that checks for collisions of circles placed randomly. If a newly added circle overlaps another it is given a new position, and the test is repeated until all circles are placed without any overlap - same type of idea.

https://editor.p5js.org/p52dcollide/sketches/WYb8vT3Mh

Or you might like to use the `p5.play` library instead.  Here's an example with objects that bounce off each other http://molleindustria.github.io/p5.play/examples/index.html?fileName=collisions4.js